# Bash Scripting: I want to open a set of .php files, and add line before html tag

Tags: bash, shell, editing

I have a set of .php files in a folder, I want to add text just before these lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
```

What i want is to insert just before these lines in the html file. So just want to prepend that file before each docType declaration. However the DOCTYPE declaration is never on line 1, as there is loads of php lines before.

I have this current script (where FE is the folder containing all the scripts i want to edit):

```
for file in ${fe}*; do
      echo "$file"
done
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
text2add="my text to add"
for file in *.php
do
  if [ -f "$file" ];then
     sed -i.bak "/<\!DOCTYPE/ i $text2add" $file
  fi
done
```

Or just simply

```
text2add="my text to add"
sed -i.bak "/<\!DOCTYPE/ i $text2add" *.php
```

If you want to do it recursively

```
find . -iname "*.php" -exec  sed -i.bak "/<\!DOCTYPE/ i $text" "{}" +;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for file in ${fe}*; do
sed -i -e '/<!DOC/i Text to insert' "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in ${fe}*; do 
    mv $file temp
    echo "YOUR STRING" > $FILE
    cat temp >> $FILE;
done
```

Comment: But i dont want to simply prepend some text to the file, i want to search for that text and add some text before it

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "line" | cat - yourfile > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out yourfile
```

Taken from here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-prepend-text-lines-to-file/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposition. It assumes that your text to insert is in a file named `mytextfile`.

```
for file in ${fe}*; do
    awk '/!DOCTYPE/{printf"%s\n",text;}{print}' text="`cat mytextfile`" $file \
        > /tmp/out
    mv /tmp/out $file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in perl:

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's/\<\!DOCTYPE/text to replace\<\!DOCTYPE/ig' *.php
```

This one-liner will modify all your php files, replacing `<!DOCTYPE` with whatever you want + `<!DOCTYPE` -- you want to put it back in (-: This will also backup all the modified files with an extension of .bak, so you'll see ".php.bak" files after you run this.

The i refers to case insensitive and g is global, i.e., replace all in the file. I assume only have one, and it has the same case, so you can safely leave out the "ig" at the end.